# ¿Como calcular una fecha a partir de otra fecha php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Tengo el siguiente código, quisiera que por favor me ayuden.. tengo dos campos donde ingreso dos fechas: fecha de apareamiento y fecha de probable parto; lo que quiero es que al ingresar o seleccionar la fecha de apareamiento, la fecha de probable parto se muestre automáticamente, contando 114 dias a partir de la fehca de apareamiento... que no sea necesario que se ingrese la fecha de probable parto, sino que se calcule y se muestre automáticamente!!
>   Gracias!!
>
> Este es el código que uso:

```html
<?php
//sesion de roles
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 and $_SESSION['rol'] != 2 and $_SESSION['rol'] != 3) 
{ 

 header("location: ./");
}
  include "../conexion.php";
  //validar que no vallan vacios los campos
  if(!empty($_POST))
 {
  $alert='';
  if(empty($_POST['cod_cuadra']) || empty($_POST['codigo_cerdo']) || empty($_POST['codigo_cerdo_v']) || empty($_POST['fecha_apareamiento']) || empty($_POST['fecha_p_parto']) || empty($_POST['fecha_parto']) 
   || empty($_POST['n_lechones_vivos'])  || empty($_POST['n_lechones_muertos'])  || empty($_POST['n_lechones_modificados']) || empty($_POST['n_lechones_destete']) 
   || empty($_POST['n_lechones_venta']))
  {
   $alert='<p class="mgs_error">Todos los campos son obligatorios.</p>';
  }else{

   $cod_cuadra  = $_POST['cod_cuadra'];
   $codigo_cerdo  = $_POST['codigo_cerdo'];
   $codigo_cerdo_v = $_POST['codigo_cerdo_v'];
   $fecha_apareamiento   = $_POST['fecha_apareamiento'];
   $fecha_p_parto  = ($_POST['fecha_p_parto']);
   $fecha_parto = $_POST['fecha_parto'];
   $n_lechones_vivos = $_POST['n_lechones_vivos'];
   $n_lechones_muertos = $_POST['n_lechones_muertos'];
   $n_lechones_modificados = $_POST['n_lechones_modificados'];
   $n_lechones_destete = $_POST['n_lechones_destete'];
   $n_lechones_venta = $_POST['n_lechones_venta'];
   
   $result = 0;

    include "../conexion.php";
    $query_insert = mysqli_query($conection,"INSERT INTO parenderas_ciclo (cod_cuadra, cod_parendera, cod_cerdo_verraco, fecha_apareamiento, fecha_probable_parto, fecha_parto,
            n_lechones_vivos, n_lechones_muertos, n_lechones_modificados, n_lechones_destete, n_lechones_venta)  
            VALUES ('$cod_cuadra', '$codigo_cerdo', '$codigo_cerdo_v', '$fecha_apareamiento', '$fecha_p_parto','$fecha_parto', '$n_lechones_vivos',
            '$n_lechones_muertos', '$n_lechones_modificados', '$n_lechones_destete', '$n_lechones_venta')");
    if ($query_insert) {
      $alert = '<p class="mgs_save">Cerdo registrado correctamente.</p>';
    }else{
     $alert = '<p class="mgs_error">Error al registrar el cerdo.</p>';
    } 

   }
  }
   
   mysqli_close($conection); 
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
    <title>Registro Ciclo Parenderas</title>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="img/cerdo.png">

  </head>

  <body class="fondo">
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <section id="container">
      <div class="from_register">
        <h1><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Ciclo de Parenderas</h1>

        <hr>

        <div class="alert">
          <?php echo isset($alert) ? $alert : ''; ?>
        </div>
        <!--mensajes -->
        <form action="" method="post">

          <!-- datos de la tabla cuadra -->
          <label for="cod_cuadra">Cuadra</label>

          <?php
       include "../conexion.php";
      $query_cuadra = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM cuadra");
      mysqli_close($conection);
      $result_cuadra = mysqli_num_rows($query_cuadra);
      ?>

            <select name="cod_cuadra" id="cod_cuadra">
              <option disabled selected>Selecciona la cuadra</option>
              <?php 
       if ($result_cuadra > 0) 
       {
        while ($cod_cuadra = mysqli_fetch_array($query_cuadra)) {
      ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $cod_cuadra[" cod_cuadra "]; ?>">
                <?php echo $cod_cuadra["descripcion_cuadra"];?>
              </option>

              <?php     
        }
       }

      ?>
            </select>

            <div class="wd41" id="cerdos">
              <!-- codigo cerda Parendera -->
              <div class="wd31">
                <label for="codigo_cerdo">Cerda Parendera</label>
                <?php
      include "../conexion.php";
      $query_codigo_cerdo = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM cerdo WHERE cod_sexo = 1");
      mysqli_close($conection);
      $result_codigo_cerdo = mysqli_num_rows($query_codigo_cerdo);
      ?>

                  <select name="codigo_cerdo" id="codigo_cerdo">
                    <option disabled selected>Seleccione aquí</option>
                    <?php 
       if ($result_codigo_cerdo > 0) 
       {
        while ($codigo_cerdo = mysqli_fetch_array($query_codigo_cerdo)) {
      ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $codigo_cerdo[" cod_correlativo_cerdo "]; ?>">
                      <?php echo $codigo_cerdo["cod_correlativo_cerdo"];?>
                    </option>

                    <?php     
        }
       }

      ?>
                  </select>
              </div>

              <!-- codigo cerdo verraco -->
              <div class="wd31" style="margin-left: 13px">
                <label for="codigo_cerdo_v">Cerdo Verraco</label>
                <?php
      include "../conexion.php";
      $query_codigo_cerdo_v = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM cerdo WHERE (cod_sexo = 2  AND castrado = 'no')");
      mysqli_close($conection);
      $result_codigo_cerdo_v = mysqli_num_rows($query_codigo_cerdo_v);
      ?>

                  <select name="codigo_cerdo_v" id="codigo_cerdo_v">
                    <option disabled selected>Seleccione aquí</option>
                    <?php 
       if ($result_codigo_cerdo_v > 0) 
       {
        while ($codigo_cerdo_v = mysqli_fetch_array($query_codigo_cerdo_v)) {
      ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $codigo_cerdo_v[" cod_correlativo_cerdo "]; ?>">
                      <?php echo $codigo_cerdo_v["cod_correlativo_cerdo"];?>
                    </option>

                    <?php     
        }
       }

      ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>

          
            <div class="row" id="fechas">
                <!-- fecha apareamineto -->
              <div id="fecha_apareamiento"><label for="fecha_apareamiento">Fecha de apareamiento</label>
                <input type="date" name="fecha_apareamiento"></div>

              <!-- fecha probable parto -->
              <div id="fecha_p_parto"><label for="fecha_p_parto">Fecha Probable Parto</label>
                <input type="date" name="fecha_p_parto"></div>
            </div>


            <!-- fecha parto -->
            <label for="fecha_parto">Fecha de Parto</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha_parto">
            <!-- numero de lechones vivos--->
            <label for="n_lechones_vivos">Lechones vivos</label>
            <input type="number" name="n_lechones_vivos" id="n_lechones_vivos" placeholder="Lechos vivos" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)">
            <!-- numero de lechones muertos--->
            <label for="n_lechones_muertos">Lechones muertos</label>
            <input type="number" name="n_lechones_muertos" id="n_lechones_muertos" placeholder="Lechos muertos" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)">
            <!-- numero de lechones modificados--->
            <label for="n_lechones_modificados">Lechones modificados</label>
            <input type="number" name="n_lechones_modificados" id="n_lechones_modificados" placeholder="Lechos modificados" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)">
            <!-- numero de lechones en destete--->
            <label for="n_lechones_destete">Lechones en destete</label>
            <input type="number" name="n_lechones_destete" id="n_lechones_destete" placeholder="Lechos en destete" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)">
            <!-- numero de lechones en venta--->
            <label for="n_lechones_venta">Lechones vendidos</label>
            <input type="number" name="n_lechones_venta" id="n_lechones_venta" placeholder="Lechos vendidos" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)">

            <button type="submit" class="btn_save"><i class="far fa-save"></i> Registrar Ciclo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos para esto puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php
  //fecha de apareamiento
$Date = "2010-04-05";
//fecha posible parto
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 114 days'));
//salida
2010-07-28 
?>
```

Para mas detalle del uso de **strtotime** visita la documentación: [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)